# List of Abbreviations / Glossary without extra packages?

Tags: acronyms

I finished my dissertation and I have now been asked to add a list of abbreviations/glossary just after the table of contents. I have searched several examples but all seem to require extra packages that do not work on my mac (using texpad on mac os x maverick) so I was wondering if some generous soul could guide me through how to do that on a mac. It could also be done manually without packages as long as there is a good formatting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What packages have you tried? I've never had any problems whatsoever on mine.

Comment: I tried with acro.sty... problems in compiling on mac. should I just build a table or it will look bad ?

Comment: You should post an MWE with how you're using the `acro` package and edit your question accordingly.  If you want a quick-and-dirty solution and don't need much functionality, use description lists.  You can use the `enumitem` package to easily customize the appearance there.